# Transact SQL Pivot a Split String into appropriate columns

Tags: sql-server

My company is using a generic logging database among many products. To prevent the need for a lot of cross database queries some info is stored in delimited fields within the generic data columns for the logging.

I'm wanting to write query's on the data, but I'm unsure how to use Pivot/Unpivot to get the data into appropriate columns?

Below is a generic example using static data for what I'm wanting to do, but not sure how to do it. We unfortunately don't have the built in split string function in SqlServer 2016 so dbo.fnSplitString is my written equivalent which works fine.

```
 DECLARE @Columns TABLE (
     CustomerNumber VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
     FirstName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
     LastName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

/* This isn't valid SQL ... unsure how to get this to work */
INSERT INTO @Columns PIVOT SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString('STUFF1,STUFF2,STUFF3',',');

SELECT * FROM @Columns;
```

Edit:

Using the examples here and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx I was able to come up with a solution. The split string function also needs to output a position. This was inspired by one of the solutions below just 'OrdinalPosition' needed to be added to the function. The resulting query works.

```
DECLARE @Columns TABLE (CustomerNumber VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, FirstName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, LastName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Columns select [0], [1], [2] from (SELECT position, splitdata FROM  dbo.fnSplitString('STUFF1,STUFF4,STUFF3',',')) split pivot (MAX(splitdata) FOR position in ([0],[1],[2])) piv;

SELECT * FROM @Columns;
```

Comment: What is your fnSplitString function? Hopefully not the one with the while loop in it that everybody seems to find. The answer here depends on your splitter.

Comment: I assume, each string should go into each columns of the table @Columns. Right?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea @Rex, it returns a table with rows having each value. I need to transpose it into the appropriate columns for querying.

Comment: I sort of assumed it did that. Some splitters return just the values and others return the ordinal position. You need a way to order your results so you know which value belongs to which column.

Comment: It always returns the first delimited value in position 0, second in position 1, etc. For the types of querying we will do we can assume the insertion order is static.

Comment: Could you post that function? Of course it returns the rows in that order but you are going to need to know which row a given row is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function fnSplitString returns a table then simply

```
INSERT INTO @Columns 
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString('STUFF1,STUFF2,STUFF3',',')
PIVOT
(
MAX(ParsedValue)
FOR OrdinalPosition in ([0], [1], [2], [3])
) x
```

Comment: Assuming it is a typical splitter it would return the delimited values as rows.

Comment: Yeah this is the problem it returns them as rows.

Comment: @user2927848 It now uses the ordinal position

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:
I just used "item" as column name. Replace it with the name corresponding to your name that is returned from fnSplitString function.

```
DECLARE @Columns TABLE (CustomerNumber VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, FirstName 
VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, LastName VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO @Columns
select STUFF1,STUFF2,STUFF3 from (SELECT  item FROM 
dbo.fnSplitString('STUFF1,STUFF2,STUFF3',',')) d
pivot ( max(item)  for item in (STUFF1,STUFF2,STUFF3) ) piv;

SELECT * FROM @Columns;
```

Comment: This seems close but it the pivot orders them by MAX I'd like them to be transposed by the position they are in the string.